# Maven release plugin incompatible with Gitlab groups?

Tags: git, maven, jenkins, gitlab, maven-release-plugin

I'm using these  informations in my the pom.xml for my aggregator project :

```
<scm>
  <connection>
    scm:git:git@gitlab.mycomp.fr:LInC/outilconseiller.git
  </connection>
  <developerConnection>
    scm:git:git@gitlab.mycomp.fr:LInC/outilconseiller.git
  </developerConnection>
  <tag>HEAD</tag>
</scm>
```

But when I use maven-release-plugin through Jenkins, here is what happens :

```
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/OutilsConseiller/workspace/outil-conseiller-aggregator && git push git@gitlab.mycomp.fr:LInC/outilconseiller.git refs/heads/master:refs/heads/master
```

(good URL here : git@gitlab.mycomp.fr:LInC/outilconseiller.git)

(some more logs...)

```
[INFO] Tagging release with the label outil-conseiller-aggregator-1.4.9...
```

(some more logs...)

```
[INFO] Executing: /bin/sh -c cd /var/lib/jenkins/jobs/OutilsConseiller/workspace && git push git@gitlab.mycomp.fr:LInC refs/tags/outil-conseiller-aggregator-1.4.9
```

(Bad URL here : git push git@gitlab.mycomp.fr:LInC with no "/outilconseiller.git" !)

And the last push gives :

```
Command output:
GitLab: The project you were looking for could not be found.
```

So is it a known bug of maven-release-plugin ? of Jenkins ? Why is he removing the last part of my git URL in some pushes ?

When I had a git URL with no "/" in it, releases were working just fine through jenkins.

Comment: Why are you not using "git@gitlab.mycomp.fr/LInC/outilconseiller.git" instead of "git@gitlab.mycomp.fr:LInC/outilconseiller.git"?

Comment: Because it's how Gitlab gives you an SSH URL on the main page of a project (same for Github).

Comment: I've tried your suggestion though, but if fails even earlier : [ERROR] fatal: 'git@gitlab.mycomp.fr/LInC/outilconseiller.git' does not appear to be a git repository

Comment: I've also tried to prefix with ssh:// (so ssh://git@gitlab.mycomp.fr/LInC/outilconseiller.git), and it uses the full URL for the first push and a truncated URL for the second push exactly like in my original question. Note : for the 2 possible syntaxes of SSH URL, see : https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols

Comment: I've also tried to upgrade from maven-release-plugin v2.5.1 to v2.5.3 and I have the same result. So if no one has ideas or my question gets burried after week end, I'll just give up this crappy tool who make me lose so much time and move to a more manual process using versions-maven-plugin