# How to tell versions-maven plugin to act on non-child modules?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin, maven-release-plugin, maven-versions-plugin

I have a multi-module project where all modules are in the same directory as the "aggregator" module. The aggregator is **NOT** the parent of the modules, it's only there to spread any maven command to modules, but there is no inheritance.

When I do this (maven-release-plugin command) in the aggregator directory :

```
mvn --batch-mode release:update-versions -DdevelopmentVersion=1.1.1-SNAPSHOT -DautoVersionSubmodules=true
```

It does change the version of all modules, but when I do this :

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.1.1-SNAPSHOT
```

It does not, it changes only the aggregator module version.

Note : I know when you have a parent-child relationship between aggregator and modules you don't meet this problem.

Comment: If you are already using release plugin why do you need versions-maven-plugin?

Comment: Because it's buggy, especially when you are using a flat directory layout and when you are using Git. But if versions-maven-plugin is just as buggy, I won't be able to do the transition described here : https://axelfontaine.com/blog/final-nail.html

Comment: Which version of maven-release-plugin do you use? Apart from that please open a issue against the maven-release-plugin... And why do you need to use a flat directory layout instead of the hierarchically?

Comment: There are already multiple issues open about this from years ago, they just don't care. There was some workaround though (using push/fetch URL as developerConnection). About versions-maven-plugin, I've opened this one : https://github.com/mojohaus/versions-maven-plugin/issues/136

Comment: And about the flat layout, I add the aggregator (non-parent) module only when I need it, after my app has spread on multiple modules, and Maven allows this so I shouldn't have to anticipate this nor to have to "git mv" everything and probably lose code history.

Comment: Sorry to say that. You are not answering questions. Which version of maven-release-plugin and versions-maven-plugin are you using? Furthermore if you see there is a problem why not offering a patch and active helping to solve a problem. You have opened an [issue](https://github.com/mojohaus/versions-maven-plugin/issues/136) but this references to two year old informations (old version of versions-maven-plugin) and does not contain an example project which shows the wrong behaviour...

Comment: Why harrass me with this man ? can't u assume I'm using the latest version if u have the intent to try to reproduce ? I tried with 2.5.1 and 2.5.3 for Maven release plugin, see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42863170/maven-release-plugin-incompatible-with-gitlab-groups and as I say, there are workarounds for this bug so my concern is about versions-maven-plugin (YES LATEST VERSION TOO !). This issue I've opened give all necessary informations for someone who has time and competences to correct the plugin (which I have not) and yes, it gives an example project.